# the or this in $(the).parents("tr")

Tags: jquery

I am following an instruction to dig jQuery:

The template:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
  <td>{{ column.column }}</td>
  <td>
      <a onclick="edit_column(this, {{ column.id }})" name="edit" href="javascript:">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      </a>
      <a onclick="delete_column(this, {{ column.id }})" name="delete" href="javascript:">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="margin-left:20px;"></span>
     </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Edit content with

```
function edit_column(the, column_id){
    var name = $(the).parents("tr").children("td").eq(1).text();
```

When changed `the` to `this`, it throw error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

What's `the` here which seems not exist in jQuery specification.

Comment: the the is pointing to the clicked element. why change the to this anyway?

Comment: `this` is a reserved keyword so you can't use it as a name for a function argument.

Comment: I got it, `the` is `e` as `event`.@guradio

Comment: No, it's not the event. You're calling the function with `this` as the first argument, and `the` is the local variable that contains that parameter.

Comment: The programmer just need to use a different variable for the parameter. It can be just about anything, but it can't be a reserved word like `this`.

Comment: Could you please transmit the concise comment to answer for further reference. @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a special keyword in Javascript, it can't be used as an ordinary variable name.

So this function uses `the` as the name of its first parameter. It receives the value of `this` from the callers, because of `onclick=edit_column(this, {{ column.id }})`. In the context of `onclick` execution, `this` is the element that was clicked on.

The name of the function parameter could be any variable, the programmer just chose to use `the` as the name. But you can't change it to `this` because that's not a valid variable name.